# How to get sum of array nested in object?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
{service: {  
  categories: [
      {
          name: "category1",
          id: 1,
          questions: [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  question: "example trivia question here",
                  value: 2
              }, {
                  id: 2,
                  question: "example trivia question here",
                  value: 3
              }]
      },
    {
        name: "category2",
        id: 2,
        questions: [
            {
                id: 3,
                question: "example trivia question here",
                value: 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "category3",
        id: 3
    }
]
}};
```

For each category, I'm trying to count the answered trivia question. How do I get the sum of answered questions for each category (indicated when there is a value present)? I think there's something gone wrong in my loop. I've also tried this with array prototypes. Sorry for the noob question.

```
$scope.questionCount = 0;

angular.forEach($scope.service, function(categories, questions) {
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].value !== null){
      triviaCount = 0
      triviaCount += 1
      $scope.questionCount.push(triviaCount)
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You reset `triviaCount` to zero in every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: I think you want something like `angular.forEach($scope.service.categories, function(category){...})` on the top level? Then inside that, another loop like you have going through that category's questions. You're not actually accessing the questions property at any point in your current code - just creating a variable called "questions" that gets filled with each of the iterated object's keys, from the forEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method provided by Array

```
var service = {  
  categories: [
      {
          name: "category1",
          id: 1,
          questions: [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  question: "example trivia question here",
                  value: 2
              }, {
                  id: 2,
                  question: "example trivia question here",
                  value: 3
              }]
      },
    {
        name: "category2",
        id: 2,
        questions: [
            {
                id: 3,
                question: "example trivia question here",
                value: 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "category3",
        id: 3
    }
]
};


var result = service.categories.map(function(cat) {
    return { 
        'name' : cat.name, 
        'count' : !!cat.questions ? cat.questions.length : 0
    }
});

console.log(result);
// [{ name="category1",  count=2}, { name="category2",  count=1}, { name="category3",  count=0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? (look at the console)

console output:

```
category1  # of quesitons:  2
category2  # of quesitons:  1
category3  # of quesitons:  0
```

```js
var service = {  
    categories: [
        {
            name: "category1",
            id: 1,
            questions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: 2
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: 3
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: '',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "category2",
            id: 2,
            questions: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: 5
                },
                {
                    id: 7,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: '',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "category3",
            id: 3,
            questions: [],
        }
    ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
 for(var i = 0; i < service.categories.length; i++ ){
        var questionCount = 0;
     for(var j = 0; j < service.categories[i].questions.length; j++ ) {
         if (service.categories[i].questions[j].value != '' && service.categories[i].questions[j].value != undefined) {
             questionCount++;
            }            
        }
        console.log(service.categories[i].name, ' # of quesitons: ', questionCount);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: in your code you can just do `questionCount=service.categories[i].questions.length` without loop

Comment: okay. I'm following. However, this seems to count every question. I'm only trying to count questions that have a 'value' .

Comment: @NewGuy504 ok, so are you trying to count the questions that have value like, 2 questions have a value, so the output is 2, or are you trying to count the value of the questions like: 2 questions have a value of 5 and 3, so output 8?

Comment: @NewGuy504, i altered my code above to count questions that contain a value that is not '' or undefined. please take a look and see if it helps you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to with angular js but this is how i will do with js. i hope this helps you.

```
    var json = {
        service: {
            categories: [{
                name: "category1",
                id: 1,
                questions: [{
                    id: 1,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: 2
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: 3
                }]
            }, {
                name: "category2",
                id: 2,
                questions: [{
                    id: 3,
                    question: "example trivia question here",
                    value: 5
                }]
            }, {
                name: "category3",
                id: 3
            }]
        }
    };

    var qCount = 0;

    categories = json.service.categories;
    for (var category in categories) {
        var temp = categories[category];
        if (temp.questions !== undefined) {
            var questions = temp.questions;
            for (var que in questions) {
                if (questions[que].value !== undefined)
                    qCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(qCount); //here is your question count
```